# jQuery blur event triggers twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery-1.4.4 in one of my projects and I have been facing a problem, i.e., blur event for one of the input element is triggers twice.Please help me and the functionality is given below.

```
$(function () {
    $('.cardnumber').keyup(function () {
        //Need to call a function
    }).focus(function () {
        //Need to call a function
    }).blur(function () {
        console.log('blur');
    });

    $('.cardnumber').focus().blur(); 
});
```

Comment: Firstly, 1.4.4 is very outdated, can you not update it? Secondly, why are you immediately raising `focus` and `blur` events?

Comment: Your CSS selector `.cardnumber` points to a CSS class, not an element. Do you have two HTML elements with the class `cardnumber`? I think you should include your HTML in your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, as @Krumia suggests, paste your HTML. There may be two elements that have that `cardnumber` class.

Comment: I could replicate this behavior in stack snippets with `n` HTML elements having the CSS class `cardnumber` (And `console.log` executes `n` times). Unfortunately I cannot post it as an answer without knowing your exact code. Cannot create a JSFiddle because they don't support jQuery 1.4.4.

Comment: @Krumia you can use external resources in Fiddle. Use this if you want to make an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/xpmp1jq6/2/

Comment: Cannot replicates issue on chrome  http://jsfiddle.net/xpmp1jq6/3/ . Which browser are you using? What are you trying to do? Maybe trigger handlers (focus/blur or both)  `.triggerHandler('blur')`

Comment: I have already inspected in DOM that I don't have two elements with 'cardnumber' that particular class. @Krumia

Comment: Hello @Rory McCrossan, I can't upgrade to 1.9 and higher, because so much functionality depends on that j Query version and if I upgraded to that version there so many deprecated methods in 1.9 and it's causing me to disturbance in the functionality, and one more thing is I want to trigger both events one after another because when the user focused into input then I need to display the card number with hyphens and when the user focused out from the input, I need to display in the manner of XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1111.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `$('cardnumber').focus().blur()` has be default it will trigger on load just use .

```
$(function () {
    $('.cardnumber').keyup(function () {
        //Need to call a function
    }).focus(function () {
        //Need to call a function
    }).blur(function () {
        console.log('blur');
    });
});
```

it should trigger only after you have entered the value in the cardnumber

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the following demo, `blur` triggers only once. Therefore, it is safe to say that some other piece of code must be responsible for the second trigger.

**One way the issue can be caused is if you have a second `.cardnumber` element in your markup. Therefore, check to ensure you have one or if there are more and you wish to target just one, then use: `$('.cardnumber').first().focus().blur();` to target the first, for example.**

Also as noted in the comments use a current version of jQuery.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.cardnumber').keyup(function () {
        //Need to call a function
    }).focus(function () {
        //Need to call a function
    }).blur(function () {
        console.log('blur');
    });

    $('.cardnumber').focus().blur(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="cardnumber" type="text" name="cardnumber" />
```

**TWO Elements**: - blur triggers twice

```js
    $(function () {
        $('.cardnumber').keyup(function () {
            //Need to call a function
        }).focus(function () {
            //Need to call a function
        }).blur(function () {
            console.log('blur');
        });

        $('.cardnumber').focus().blur(); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="cardnumber" type="text" name="cardnumber1" />
<input class="cardnumber" type="text" name="cardnumber2" />
```

**SOLUTION** -- target one

```js
        $(function () {
            $('.cardnumber').keyup(function () {
                //Need to call a function
            }).focus(function () {
                //Need to call a function
            }).blur(function () {
                console.log('blur');
            });

            $('.cardnumber').first().focus().blur(); 
        });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input class="cardnumber" type="text" name="cardnumber1" />
    <input class="cardnumber" type="text" name="cardnumber2" />
```